# What value passes from a form with checkbox to the java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I take a form and wants value of checkbox.
such as:

```
<form method="post" onSubmit="return nameempty()">

<input name="checkn1" id="check1" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkn2" id="check2" type="checkbox" />

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Now I want to know the values of checkbox when it is selected, and also when not selected.

Now I write javascript, and get that each checkbox has value "on" whether it is selected or not.

```
<script>
function nameempty()
{
alert(document.getElementById('check1').value);
alert(document.getElementById('check2').value);
}
</script>
```

How could I get 'on' when it is selected and anything else when not selected.

Comment: I am new in this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `checked` instead of `value` which will return true if the checkbox is checked or it will return false

```
<script>
function nameempty()
{
alert(document.getElementById('check1').checked);
alert(document.getElementById('check2').checked);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the value of a 'checked' check box which includes the check if 'checked'

```
var check1value = document.querySelector('#check1:checked').value;
```

In the html you are missing a value attribute (if checked)

```
<input name="checkn1" id="check1" value="value-here" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: how could I get "off" when not selected ?

Comment: Actually when second box is selected and first is not selected then no alert is shown.